# Prove $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$

Logically, this is clearly true. I can explain why: start with $A$, remove all elements in $B$ and then add in any elements in both $A$ and $B$, which restores you back to $A$. That's an explanation, but AFAIK, it's not a proof in the formal proof sense.

I submitted a proof by a truth table which considers the four possible scenarios where an element is in/not in $A$/$B$. My professor asked me to redo the proof without a truth table.

My question is what mechanisms and strategies can I use to prove this in a acceptable formal proof sense?

Comment: "If $a\in A$ then either it's also in $B$ or it's not" ... (in fact, $A=(A\cap B)\color{Red}{\sqcup}(A\setminus B)$)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual way to prove that two sets are equal is by *element-chasing*: Choose an arbitrary element of one set and show it's in the other, and then do it again in the opposite direction.

So for example, suppose $x \in A$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cap B$ and we're done; if $x \notin B$, then $x \in A \setminus B$ and we're again done.

Now suppose $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$, and prove that $x \in A$.

Comment: perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For completeness's sake, here is a proof using just the rules of [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)).  Let $U$ be the universal set.  Then:

$$A = A\cap U = A \cap (\overline B \cup B) = (A \cap \overline B) \cup (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) $$

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$, then:
 $$(x \in A \wedge x \notin B) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B)\equiv x\in A \wedge(x\notin B  \vee x \in B)$$
but $x\notin B  \vee x \in B$, is the  universe of 
reference (universal set)  $U$, then

$$ x\in A \wedge(x\notin B  \vee x \in B)\equiv A \cap U=A$$

Comment: very helpful. thanks! If I could accept both I would