# How to prove $A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How to prove $A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$. I have seen this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843081) and the solution is clear to me. Initially I was satisfied by my prove but now I think it is wrong.

**How I have proved**

$$(A\cup B)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)\\
  (A\cup B)\cap A=[(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)]\cap A=[(A\setminus B)\cap A]\cup[(A\cap B)\cap A]\cup[(B\setminus A)\cap A]\\
  A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup\phi=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$$

Have I proved it correctly. If yes then how? I mean that I have used $A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$ and $B=(B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$ to get the $(A\cup B)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ and then I'm using it to prove $A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$. This means that I'm using a statement to prove itself!

Kindly help me.

Comment: I think it's better to use \setminus instead of "-" for difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.  If you start by assuming what you are trying to prove, then whatever follows doesn't prove anything.

The question you linked has several correct proofs, if you want to see the right way to go about proving this.  (I just added [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360436/85153) to that question proving the claim directly using the algebra of sets, which might be the kind of proof you're looking for.)

Comment: Thank you sir for understanding what I was really asking.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that if $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in (A \setminus B) \lor x \in (A \cap B)$

$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in B^{\complement}) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B)$

$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A) \land (x \in B \lor x \in B^{\complement})$

$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A) \land (x \in U)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A$

Comment: Should use two-way arrows, otherwise this only proves that $(A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A$.

Comment: @augurar Thanks for highlighting the mistake. updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)=(A\cap B')\cup (A\cap B)$

Take $(A\cap B)=X$, then we have,

$$(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)=(A\cap B')\cup X$$
$$=(A\cup X)\cap (B'\cup X)$$
$$=A\cap (A \cup B')=A$$

To finish the proof show that: $(A\cup X)=A$ and $(B'\cup X)=(A\cup B')$

Can you finish from here?