# Proof on set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was making a few exercises on set proofs but I met an exercise on which I don't know how to start:

> If $A \cap C = B \cap C $ and $ A-C=B-C $ then $A = B$

Where should I start? Should I start from $ A \subseteq B $ or should I start from this $ ((A\cap C = B\cap C) \land  (A-C = B-C)) \Rightarrow (A = B)$ ?

Comment: A hint that can help you: $A-C=A\cap C^c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show $A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, as one usually would when showing that two sets are equal. Since the conditions are symmetric in $A$ and $B$, the two proofs are completely analoguous, so I will only do one of them.

To show $A \subseteq B$, take an $a \in A$, and note that either $a \in C$ or $a \notin C$. If $a \in C$, then we have $a \in A\cap C$. If $a\notin C$, then we have $a \in A-C$. In both cases, you may use the given set equalities to conclude that $a \in B$. This shows $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought of something like this, but I wasn't sure if it was proper /formal!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A\cap C&=B\cap C\\
A-C&=B-C
\end{align}
Take the union of the left- and right-hand sides:
\begin{align}
(A\cap C)\cup(A-C)&=(B\cap C)\cup(B-C)\\
(A\cap C)\cup(A\cap\overline C)&=(B\cap C)\cup(B\cap\overline C)\\
A\cup(C\cap\overline C)&=B\cup(C\cap\overline C)\\
A&=B
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$A=(A \cap C)\cup(A-C)=(B \cap C)\cup(B-C)= B.$$
1st and last equality proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360411/how-to-prove-a-a-setminus-b-cup-a-cap-b), and the middle one is your assumptions.

Comment: user1868607 you have not [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) any answer to any question you asked. Do you think all answers are unacceptable?