# Proof of $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$ using the laws of set algebra.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Q.Prove: $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$

I want to prove it using set laws.

But I am lacking of any hint to break L.H.S into any usable result.
Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: By "set laws", what exactly do you mean? There are many different sets of set laws.

Comment: Oops!The title has been edited.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360436/312318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=A\cap (B\cup\bar{B})=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap\bar{B})=(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)$

Answer (score 1):

You could take an arbitrary x that belongs to one side, and show that it belongs to the other side.

let $x \in A$

2 possibilites:

1. $x \in B$ then $x \in A\cap B$. Then $ x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A-B) $
2. $x \notin B$ then $x \notin A \cap B$ but $ x \in (A-B)$ Then $ x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A-B) $

Then $ A \subset x \in (A \cap B) \cap (A-B) $

let $ x \in x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A-B)$

2 possibilites:

1. $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A \wedge x \in B $. Then $x \in A $.
2. $x \in (A-B)$. Then $ x \in A \wedge x \notin B$. Then $x \in A.

Then $(A \cap B) \cup (A-B) \subset A$

Then $ A=(A \cap B) \cup (A-B)$