# Write a set as union of disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was arguing with my roommate about writing **any** set like this:
$A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$ 
Asuming, that both $A, B \subseteq X$, where X is the Universe.
No matter what the relationship between $A$ and $B$ is, I think my reasoning is correct, because I can prove that with a double inclusion argument.

Comment: Note that you may not have actually managed to write $A$ as a disjoint union of _nonempty_ sets. If it happens that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then you have $\emptyset\cup A$ as your disjoint union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of some common set $X$, this is an immediate consequence of the distributive property:
$$ (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)=A\cap (B\cup B^c)=A\cap X=A$$

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685672/proofs-involving-a-setminus-b-cup-a-cap-b/1685677#1685677), there are proofs for $A = (A\setminus B) \cup (A \cap B).$ It is easy to see that $(A \cap B^c)=(A\setminus B).$

Comment: you are welcome