# Given $3$ sets if $A \cap B = A \cap C$. Is $B=C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to solve this question for a while but I just seem to be missing something.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three sets.

If $ A \cap B = A \cap C$

Is $ B=C $ ?

Comment: Let $A=\emptyset$

Comment: Or $A=\{1\}$, $B = \{2\}$, $C = \{3\}$... one wonders if the OP even tried any possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. 
@Bungo I did try, it is hard for me to visualize sets. I'm good with numbers but sets just bug me...  I apologize if I wasted your time.

Comment: No.  Let A be {one single four leaf clover}.  Let B be {everything on the planet earth}.  Let C be {everything that is green in the universe}.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $$A=\left\{1,2,3 \right\}$$
$$B=\left\{1,2,3,4,5 \right\}$$
$$C=\left\{1,2,3,6,7 \right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

All possible sets of $C$ are all sets which contains$ A \cap B$ and not contains $\overline{A} \cap B$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true iff in addition $B\setminus A=C\setminus A$:

[$B = (B\setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685672/proofs-involving-a-setminus-b-cup-a-cap-b/1685677#1685677)$=(C\setminus A) \cup (A \cap C)=C.$

If $B\setminus A\neq C\setminus A$ you can construct counterexample by adding element (to $A \cap C$)  that differs in $B\setminus A$ and $C\setminus A. $ This is what you  see in comments and answer.